# Mounting iPad (iOS 8) on Ubuntu 14.04 disaster

Tags: mount, clementine, ipad

So I have an iPad with iOS 8 installed and I wanted to connect it to my computer to transfer some music. Here's what happened (in excruciating detail):

1. I connected the iPad and tried to open it as a device with Clementine; gave me Unhandled Lockdown Error
2. I proceeded to install a bunch of packages around libimobiledevice (including libimobiledevice-utils, ifuse, some stuff these packages seemed to depend on)
3. Then I noticed that the iPad is asking whether or not to trust the computer and when I clicked yes, it connected (yay me); for some reason it wouldn't take the songs I tried to upload
4. I connected it again and it mounted twice as an iPad (giving an error for trying to mount the same device twice) and once as an iPhone (giving an unhandled lockdown error again); bonus points because the whole computer just froze when I tried to open the iPad in the file browser and I had to force-restart it
5. I went through the apt history log file and deleted as many of the packages I installed as possible (thinking they were conflicting in some way)
6. Still when I connect the iPad, I get two iPads and an iPhone, and to make me even happier, it freezes to the point of force-restart

Comment: Not a solution but is a never ending story, everytime a new iOS is released by Apple support breaks until next release of Ubuntu (linimoviledecive) and history repeat itself since Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Very reassuring :D
I'm pretty sure in this case I broke it because it was working in the beginning...

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Supposedly, the newest libimobiledevice and libplist support iOS 8, but I have not found a sane way to install them in Ubuntu (I did find several ways to break my apt by installing packages whose dependencies it could not find).

Comment: As xangua wrote, this is a problem that constantly repeats itself. Sadly. I can say that 14.04 LTS handled iPhone 6 running iOS 8.2 just fine. Was able to browse and move pictures and videos off the phone. Then, I updated iOS 8.3 this weekend. You guessed it- now 14.04 LTS can't mount the iPhone. I had to take the update because of battery life problems, which iOS 8.3 did seem to fix. I'll have to wait for the library to catch up. I am Windows-free, and don't have Mac, so I am unable to run iTunes. I guess that is not a user model that Apple likes. CatAndMouse++;

Answer (score 1):

You can share files to iPad via WiFi through an ipad app that handles the SMB protocol. I used FileBrowser app available in the App Store and works for me. I had the same problem so far is the only way I've found.

Comment: This is *almost* an answer. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: This method would not allow you to import music into the native music app on the ipad (unless you are jailbroken, which is a different story). You may be able to listne to the music through some other app though. I know the Documents 5 allows can see local shares and I believe it can play music too